# ¿Cómo dibujar cualquier cosa sobre una imagen en Java?

Tags: java

lo que pasa es que necesito en un panel dibujar una imagen y quiero que se mantenga estatica y sobre ella, dibujar lineas y esas cosas, o inclusive otra imagen, pero de lo que he leido dicen que hay que hacer un BufferedImage de la imagen como tal, pero no se como hacerlo, tengo un pequeño codigo que quizá oriente un poco a lo q me refiero

```
private BufferedImage dobleBuffer;

public inicializarBufferedImage(){
    File imageFile = new File("imagen.jpg"); // guarda la imagen en un archivo
        try {
            dobleBuffer = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageFile.toString())); // la carga en una BufferedReader
        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es bastante amplia. Para dibujar puedes usar un panel de swing, luego mezclar los contextos gráficos. Mira esta respuesta de SOen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612684/drawing-in-java-using-canvas

Comment: perdona, pero es que necesito saber cómo usar una imagen igual que usaría un canvas, puede que incluso me este complicando solo y como en realidad tengo solo una vaga idea de como funiciona,  entonces cómo podria hacer que esa imagen simplemente se quede quieta y luego sobre ella pueda dibujar lo que quiera, desde una figura hasta poner una imagen, no quiero parecer atrevido pero quisiera saber como lo harias tu o que me aconsejas? a parte de tomar unas clases online del manejo de esto porque el tiempo en realidad no me deja, debo hacer esto para el fin de semana, gracias por leer :)

Comment: Hay una montaña de información por internet, mira esto para dibujar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOb1eil4PCo y esto te podria servir para cargar la imagen en el canvas de swing http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=28197 pero como te dije... hay muchos otros detalles que son mas extensos que una respuesta "comun" de SO

Comment: Lo puede hacer con un panel y en el panel el constructor paint en donde dibuja la imagen con graphics y luego con el graphics pintar las líneas o lo que quiera

Answer (score 0):

Prueba leer la imagen con este código que la manda a un `BufferedImage`:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(strRuta+ strImagenNombre)));
```